# How can i make my character change clothes on button click and so the character stays in the changed clothes?

Tags: c#

I want my character to change clothes when the player is next to the cupboard and presses the button "K". However after it just goes back to the original clothes i know why but i dont know how to make him stay in his new clothes.

code: Here is the code i dont know if using things such as "classes" is better when creating a game. thanks for any help i'm new to c#.

```
 public partial class f_game : Form
    {

        bool right,left;
        bool jump;
        int G = 13;
        int Force;

        public f_game()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pb_player.Top = pl_screen.Height - pb_player.Height;//player start position
            pb_player.Visible = false;

        }

        private void f_game_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //bed collision
            if (pb_player.Right > pb_playerbed.Left && pb_player.Left < pb_playerbed.Right - pb_player.Width / 2 && pb_player.Bottom > pb_playerbed.Top)
            {
                right = false;

            }
            if (pb_player.Left < pb_playerbed.Right && pb_player.Right > pb_playerbed.Left + pb_player.Width / 2 && pb_player.Bottom > pb_playerbed.Top)
            {
                left = false;

            }
            //door collision
            if (pb_player.Right > pb_Door.Left && pb_player.Left < pb_Door.Right - pb_player.Width / 2 && pb_player.Bottom > pb_Door.Top)
            {
                right = false;

            }

            if (right==true)
            {
                pb_player.Left += 5; ;
            }
            if (left == true)
            {
                pb_player.Left -= 5; ;
            }
            if (jump==true)
            {
                //falling
                pb_player.Top -= Force;
                Force -= 1;
            }
            if(pb_player.Top + pb_player.Height >= pl_screen.Height)
            {
                pb_player.Top = pl_screen.Height - pb_player.Height; //stops falling at bottom
                if (jump == true)
                {
                    pb_player.Image = Image.FromFile("player-stand.png");
                }
                jump = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pb_player.Top += 5;
            }

            // top collision
            if(pb_player.Left + pb_player.Width -1>pb_floor.Left&&pb_player.Left+pb_player.Width+5<pb_floor.Left+pb_floor.Width+pb_player.Width&&pb_player.Top+pb_player.Height>=pb_floor.Top && pb_player.Top < pb_floor.Top)
            {
                pb_player.Top = pl_screen.Height - pb_floor.Height-pb_player.Height;
                Force = 0;
                if (jump == true)
                {
                    pb_player.Image = Image.FromFile("player-stand.png");
                }
                jump = false;
            }



        }

        private void f_game_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Right)
            {    
              right = true;

                this.pb_player.Load("player-walk.png");
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                left = true;
                pb_player.Image = Image.FromFile("player-walkleft.png");
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            if (jump != true)
            {
                if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
                {
                    jump = true;
                    pb_player.Image = Image.FromFile("player-jump.png");
                    Force = G;
                }
            }

            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                pb_player.Visible = true;
                pb_playerbed.Image = Image.FromFile("bed.png");
                lbl_enter.Visible = false;
            }

            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.K)
            {

                if (pb_player.Right > pb_Door.Left && pb_player.Left < pb_Door.Right - pb_player.Width / 2 && pb_player.Bottom > pb_Door.Top)
                {
                    kitchen2 kitchen = new kitchen2();
                    kitchen.Show();
                    this.Hide();

                }
                else
                {                  
                    right = false;
                    pb_player.Image = Image.FromFile("interact.png");
                }
                if (pb_player.Right > pb_cupboard.Left && pb_player.Left < pb_cupboard.Right - pb_player.Width / 2 && pb_player.Bottom > pb_cupboard.Top)
                {
                    pb_player.Image = Image.FromFile("playerblue.png");

                }
                else
                {

                } 
            }
        }

        private void f_game_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Right)
            {
                pb_player.Image = Image.FromFile("player.png");
                right = false;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                left = false;
                pb_player.Image = Image.FromFile("player.png");
            }
        }
```

here is the part of the code where it changes the clothes:

```
 if(e.KeyCode == Keys.K)
                {

                    if (pb_player.Right > pb_Door.Left && pb_player.Left < pb_Door.Right - pb_player.Width / 2 && pb_player.Bottom > pb_Door.Top)
                    {
                        kitchen2 kitchen = new kitchen2();
                        kitchen.Show();
                        this.Hide();

                    }
                    else
                    {                  
                        right = false;
                        pb_player.Image = Image.FromFile("interact.png");
                    }
                    if (pb_player.Right > pb_cupboard.Left && pb_player.Left < pb_cupboard.Right - pb_player.Width / 2 && pb_player.Bottom > pb_cupboard.Top)
                    {
                        pb_player.Image = Image.FromFile("playerblue.png");

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    } 
                }
```

Comment: Could you please explain to which part of your code sample is related your question? Are you using any 3rd party library?

Comment: ye i'll edit it so you can see.

Comment: @rudolf_franek and im not using any 3rd party libaries